# slice matrix by different index arrary

Tags: python, numpy

I have a, ex 5*3 array such as

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
[10,11,12]
[13,14,15]
```

and I have 3 list to select them, ex

```
a1 = [0,1,2]
a2 = [0,1,3]
a3 = [0,2,4]
```

Now I want to get 3 array, each comes from a for a1, a2 & a3
**also, a1 selects 1st column only, a2 selects 2nd column only...** 
for given example, I want

```
[1,4,7], [2,5,11], [9,12,15]
```

What's the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [913]: arr = np.arange(1,16).reshape(5,3)                                    
In [914]: arr                                                                   
Out[914]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15]])
In [915]: idx = np.array([[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,4]])                             
In [916]: idx.shape                                                             
Out[916]: (3, 3)
```

We want to select a (3,3) array of values, where `idx` identifies rows.  So we need an column index that broadcasts with it.  `[0,1,2]` will do.

```
In [917]: arr[idx, np.arange(3)]                                                
Out[917]: 
array([[ 1,  5,  9],
       [ 1,  5, 12],
       [ 1,  8, 15]])
```

Oops, wrong selection; let's try the transpose:

```
In [918]: arr[idx.T, np.arange(3)]                                              
Out[918]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  9],
       [ 7, 11, 15]])
```